# Изменение части текста RichTextBox

Tags: .net, wpf

Можно ли изменить часть уже находящегося в RichTextBox текста, например, изменить цвет текста для этой части текста?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно. Вам нужен только [`TextPointer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textpointer(v=vs.110).aspx) на нужную позицию текста.

Имея `TextPointer` на начало текста, давайте выделим символы со второго по четвёртый:

```
var range = new TextRange(start.GetPositionAtOffset(2), start.GetPositionAtOffset(4));
range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Green);
range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Yellow);
```

Вопрос в том, как получить начало текста. Вот такой код:

```
RichTextBox rtb = ...;
FlowDocument doc = rtb.Document;
TextPointer start = doc.ContentStart;
```

не вполне верен, так как `doc.ContentStart` указывает на начало `FlowDocument`'а, за ним идёт начала `Paragraph`'а, и только затем текст. Поэтому лучше, наверное, делать так:

```
while (start != null &&
       start.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) != TextPointerContext.Text)
    start = start.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);

if (start == null)
    // в документе нет текста, выходим
```

Comment: @AN90: Пожалуйста! Рад, если помогло.

Comment: я не могу понять один момент. В ответе, как я понимаю, указываются позиции именно содержимого (не обязательно текста) в документе. Можно ли как-то определить позицию в документе фрагмента текста, если известен номер символа, с которого он начинается в строке, полученной из TextRange для всего документа? Никак не могу разобраться, но очень нужно.

Comment: @AN90: Написал ответ [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554360/10105).