# TextRange заданной части текста из RichTextBox

Tags: .net, wpf

Суть вопроса заключается в следующем. После того, как был получен текст из RichTextBox через TextRange.Text можно получить индекс подстроки в объекте string. Можно ли зная этот индекс найти TextRange, соответствующий этой подстроке в RichTextBox?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен вот такой код (сделан на основе [этого поста](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/prajakta/2006/10/12/customize-richtextbox-to-allow-only-plain-text-input-with-custom-contextmenu/)):

```
TextPointer FindPointerAtTextOffset(TextPointer from, int offset, bool seekStart)
{
    if (from == null)
        return null;

    TextPointer current = from;
    TextPointer end = from.DocumentEnd;
    int charsToGo = offset;

    while (current.CompareTo(end) != 0)
    {
        Run currentRun;
        if (current.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text &&
            (currentRun = current.Parent as Run) != null)
        {
            var remainingLengthInRun = current.GetOffsetToPosition(currentRun.ContentEnd);
            if (charsToGo < remainingLengthInRun ||
                (charsToGo == remainingLengthInRun && !seekStart))
                return current.GetPositionAtOffset(charsToGo);
            charsToGo -= remainingLengthInRun;
            current = currentRun.ElementEnd;
        }
        else
        {
            current = current.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        }
    }
    if (charsToGo == 0 && !seekStart)
        return end;
    return null;
}
```

Объяснение: во `FlowDocument`'е у вас есть различные опорные позиции: начало документа, начала абзаца, начало `Span`'а и т. п. По этим позициям можно итерировать при помощи `GetNextContextPosition`. Из них всех текст находится только внутри `Run`, а остальные — служебные. Таким образом, мы итерируем и находим все `Run`-блоки, для каждого из них мы получаем длину внутреннего текста и смотрим, в текущем блоке находится наша позиция или нет.

Использовать так. Допустим, мы хотим получить символы с 5-го по 18-ый. Пишем:

```
TextPointer start = FindPointerAtTextOffset(flowDocument.ContentStart, 5, seekStart: true);
if (start == null)
{
    // 5-ая позиция вне документа, выходим
}

TextPointer end = FindPointerAtTextOffset(start, 18 - 5, seekStart: false);
if (end == null)
{
    // 18-ая позиция вне документа, выходим
}

TextRange range = new TextRange(start, end);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!  Я пытаюсь изменить цвет части текста через TextRange этого текста. Получаю начальную и конечную позиции текста, создаю на основе позиций TextRange. Устанавливаю цвет. Цвет меняется не для той части текста - есть некоторое смещение. Иногда для фрагмента текста конечная позиция оказывается null.

Comment: @AN90: Очень странно, у меня вроде работает. Можете дать воспроизводящий пример?

Comment: Текст: "#1111111111111111#\r\n@0000000000000000@\r\n". Индекс начала фрагмента текста - 21, длина фрагмента -16 символов ("0000000000000000").