# Как выделить программно текст в RichTextBox? - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

как установить выделение в richtextbox порграммно если известны startposition и endposition?

```
TextPointer t1 = richtxt.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(startposition,LogicalDirection.Forward);
TextPointer t2 = richtxt.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(endposition, LogicalDirection.Forward);
richtxt.Selection.Select(t1,t2);
```

этот вариант не работает

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужна вспомогательная функция [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554360/10105) для точного доступа по индексу:

```
TextPointer FindPointerAtTextOffset(TextPointer from, int offset, bool seekStart)
{
    if (from == null)
        return null;

    TextPointer current = from;
    TextPointer end = from.DocumentEnd;
    int charsToGo = offset;

    while (current.CompareTo(end) != 0)
    {
        Run currentRun;
        if (current.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text &&
            (currentRun = current.Parent as Run) != null)
        {
            var remainingLengthInRun = current.GetOffsetToPosition(currentRun.ContentEnd);
            if (charsToGo < remainingLengthInRun ||
                (charsToGo == remainingLengthInRun && !seekStart))
                return current.GetPositionAtOffset(charsToGo);
            charsToGo -= remainingLengthInRun;
            current = currentRun.ElementEnd;
        }
        else
        {
            current = current.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        }
    }
    if (charsToGo == 0 && !seekStart)
        return end;
    return null;
}
```

Имея эту функцию, всё просто:

```
var flowDocument = richtxt.Document;
TextPointer start = FindPointerAtTextOffset(
        flowDocument.ContentStart, startposition, seekStart: true);
if (start == null)
{
    // позиция вне документа, выходим
    return;
}

TextPointer end = FindPointerAtTextOffset(
        start, endposition - startposition, seekStart: false);
if (end == null)
{
    // позиция вне документа, выходим
    return;
}

richtxt.Selection.Select(start, end);
richtxt.Focus();
```