# Richtextbox неправильно закрашивает символы

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

Делаю токенизатор на WPF C#, хотел сделать подсветку токенов цветом, для начала решил сделать чередование 5 красных и 5 черных символов, в результате чередование наложилось не на весь текст и еще не правильно.

```
string str_source = new TextRange(RichTextBox_input.Document.ContentStart, RichTextBox_input.Document.ContentEnd).Text + ' ';
        for (int i = 0; i < str_source.Length; i += 5)
        {
            if (i % 10 == 0)
            {
                selection_color(i, 5, new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0)));
            }
        }
```

Вот метод который написал для выделения цветом текста:

```
public void selection_color(int start,int length, SolidColorBrush color)
    {
        TextPointer textPointerStart = RichTextBox_input.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(start);
        TextPointer textPointerEnd = RichTextBox_input.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(start + length);
        var selection = RichTextBox_input.Selection;
        selection.Select(textPointerStart, textPointerEnd);
        selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, color);
    }
```

В результате получаю вот такое:
[image: Скриншот программы, привел рядом текст из Notepad]

Хотелось бы узнать в чем ошибка и почему не работает чередование 5 красных и 5 черных символов

Comment: Посмотрите это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554360/218063

Comment: И пройдитесь по этим топикам: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A10105+%5Bwpf%5D+RichTextBox