# TextPointer.GetPositionAtOffset чем он думает и почему такой неточный?

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

Предыстория: 
Выводил я лог в RichTextBox и понадобилось подсвечивать определенные фрагменты (index, length) сообщений уже после того, как они добавлены. Сделал с помощью TextRange, но пошли какие-то странные глюки - подсвечивало то там, то не там.

Стал разбираться на "сферическо-вакуумной кошке".
Вот "кошка":

```
    var txt = "Lorem ipsum blablabla";
    richTextBox1.AppendText(txt);
    //MessageBox.Show("|" + txt + "|\r\n|" + new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart,
        //richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text + "|");
    var ind = txt.IndexOf("blablabla");
    var tr = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(ind, LogicalDirection.Forward),
        richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(ind + 1, LogicalDirection.Forward));
    tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Yellow);
```

Очевидно, что должно подсвечивать первую "b" в слове "blablabla". Но подсвечивает даже не пробел, а последнюю букву "m" в слове "ipsum", т.е. отстает на 2 симв.

Теперь добавим пару лайнбреков:

```
var txt = "Lorem\r\n\r\nipsum blablabla";
```

Теперь подсвечивает вообще первую букву "i" в слове "ipsum", т.е. сдвинулось на 4 символа влево. Очевидно, \r и \n не считает за символы, а они есть.

Ну и что это за кривота??? И как бороться, кроме варианта взять исходники .NET и рефлексию?

Я долго копал свойства разных классов (TextRange и т.д.) и гуглил, но иного способа подсветить фрагмент по index-length в RTB (FlowDocument) я просто не нашел. А в гугле по WPF вообще меньше, чем по WinForms. Это уже не в первый раз для WPF: проблема есть, а всем пофигу (тредов на форумах почти не найти).

Comment: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685644/highlight-text-in-richtextbox) и [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422614/213987) -- смотрели?

Comment: @AK что-то такое находил, но не понял - причем здесь regex, у меня просто start-length... но теперь вижу, что, наверное, и без него можно. попробую...

Comment: когда уже MS создаст хоть 1 нормальное API для документов... работал с VBA Wordа, с IWebBrowser2, с RTB в WinForms, теперь FlowDocument в WPF, думал лучше будет - но, видимо, все те же кадры писали... вмазать бы тем кадрам)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/548087/10105

Comment: И у Microsoft прекрасное API. Просто оно написано не под вашу задачу, а под более общую.

Comment: @VladD ВСЁ API у него прекрасное?! теория вероятностей фигеет какие они везунчики. что самому написать? API для работы с документами? инвестируйте - напишу

Comment: @DollarDollar: Я работаю с Майкрософтовским API, и проблем никогда не было. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @VladD Возможно, дедлайны.

Comment: @DollarDollar: Вы имеете в виду, что в спешке трудно разобраться? Это да, требует времени. Но так же не только с Майкрософтовским API, и вообще не только с API.

Comment: @VlaD - Фары и ремень!

Comment: @VladD https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/421031/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-textblock-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-richtextbox/422614#422614 - между прочим, сам же писал, "странно, что там только ApplyPropertyValue". так что...

Comment: @DollarDollar: Фары и ремень хорошо, если надо быстро. А если создать язык так, чтобы можно было писать на нём не думая, то ничего хорошего не выйдет (примеры есть).

Comment: @VladD сделать отдельно TextContentStart и все. конец связи

Comment: @DollarDollar: Ну, тогда ещё InlineStart, и ещё ParagraphStart, и ещё сто тысяч свойств. И потом все будут спрашивать, какое именно нужно для их специфической задачи, и почему именно оно не вошло.

Comment: @VladD а статистику собрать по реально нужным и нужным для спец. задач? InnerHTML InnerText яркий пример. InnerDivs и InnerSpans никто не стал делать.

Comment: @DollarDollar: Вот именно поэтому InnerText и непригоден для сколько-нибудь сложного API. Потому что он безвозвратно теряет всю внутреннюю структуру. Это как раз пример ужасного API.

Answer (score 2):

> Очевидно, что должно подсвечивать первую "b" в слове "blablabla".

Нет, не очевидно. Как указано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/548087/10105), `ContentStart` указывает не на начала текста, а на начало `FlowDocument`'а, в котором сначала идёт `Paragraph` или что там в вашей структуре документа.

Попробуйте вычислить начало текста так:

```
TextPointer textStart = doc.ContentStart;
while (textStart != null &&
       textStart.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) != TextPointerContext.Text)
    textStart = textStart.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);

if (textStart == null)
{
    // в документе нет текста, выходим
}
```

и используйте `textStart` вместо `richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart`.

Comment: так и делаю, попробую сейчас, но такое впечатление, что GetNextContextPosition может потребоваться несколько раз вызывать, именно ПОСЛЕ найденного фрагмента с текстом, а не только ДО. ну может же быть несколько Paragraph, а мне, допустим, надо не 1-ый, а 2-ой

Comment: @DollarDollar: Ну да, просто не забывайте, что следующая позиция может быть и нетекстовая. Если вам нужно, к примеру, третья буква в пятом `Paragraph`'е, то сначала найдите этот `Paragraph`. потом пройдите от него до начала текста, и оттуда ещё на 5 позиций. Это только в случае, если у вас один текст.

Comment: комментарий ничего не прояснил. вопрос: то, что получится после вашего цикла - это весь текст или лишь 1 абзац?

Comment: @DollarDollar: То, что получается после цикла — начало текста в документе. Первая позиция вставки, у которой справа текст, если быть точным.